# How can I use a column from one join within another?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return organisations whose earliest quote in the past year was the first quote in a 12 month period.

Obviously this will use an `INNER JOIN` eventually, but I'm still constructing the query, starting with the sub-queries, and I want to ensure that it's working.

Unfortunately, I seem to have hit a bit of a wall, in that I need to apply the results of a `JOIN` as criteria in another `JOIN`, as follows:

Table: **Organisation**

```
orgID | orgName
------+--------------------------
    1 | ACME Widget Corp
    2 | Widget Manufacturing, Inc
```

Table: **Quote**

```
qID | qOrgID | qDateCreated
----+--------+-------------
  1 |      1 | 2015-02-10
  2 |      1 | 2015-03-16
  3 |      2 | 2015-01-10
  4 |      2 | 2015-04-20
  5 |      2 | 2016-04-10
  6 |      1 | 2016-04-07
```

Here's my query so far.

```
SELECT orgID, orgName EarliestQuote, PreviousQuote
FROM Organisation
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(qDateCreated) AS EarliestQuote, qOrgID
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT qDateCreated, qOrgID
        FROM Quote
        WHERE qDateCreated > GETDATE() -365
    ) NewerQuotes
    GROUP BY qOrgID
) eQuotes
ON eQuotes.qOrgID = orgID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(qDateCreated) AS PreviousQuote, qOrgID
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT qDateCreated, qOrgID
        FROM Quote
        WHERE qDateCreated < EarliestQuote
    ) OlderQuotes
    GROUP BY qOrgID
) pQuotes
ON pQuotes.qOrg = orgID
ORDER BY orgName
```

I'm hoping to get the following data returned:

```
orgID | orgName                   | EarliestQuote | PreviousQuote
------+---------------------------+---------------+--------------
    1 | Acme Widget Corp          | 2016-04-07    | 2015-03-16
    2 | Widget Manufacturing, Inc | 2016-04-10    |
```

Instead, I'm getting the following error: `Invalid column name 'EarliestQuote'` which obviously means I can't reference from within one join a column name retrieved in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
;WITH Organisation AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'ACME Widget Corp'),(2, 'Widget Manufacturing, Inc')
) as t(orgID, orgName)
), Quote AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 1, '2015-02-10'),(2, 1, '2015-03-16'),(3, 2, '2015-01-10'),
(4, 2, '2015-04-20'),(5, 2, '2016-04-10'),(6, 1, '2016-04-07')
) as t(qID, qOrgID, qDateCreated)
)
, cte AS (
SELECT  o.orgID, 
        o.orgName,
        q.qDateCreated,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY o.orgID, o.orgName ORDER BY q.qDateCreated) as dr
FROM Organisation o
INNER JOIN Quote q 
    ON q.qOrgID = o.orgID
)

SELECT  c.orgID,
        c.orgName,
        MAX(c.qDateCreated) as EarliestQuote,
        MAX(c1.qDateCreated) as PreviousQuote
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte c1 
    ON c.orgID = c1.orgID AND DATEDIFF(month,c1.qDateCreated,c.qDateCreated) > 12 AND c.dr - c1.dr = 1
GROUP BY c.orgID,
        c.orgName
```

Output:

```
orgID       orgName                   EarliestQuote PreviousQuote
----------- ------------------------- ------------- -------------
1           ACME Widget Corp          2016-04-07    2015-03-16
2           Widget Manufacturing, Inc 2016-04-10    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to go away and find out how it works... :/

Comment: At first we join organizations and quotes. Add dense_rank to numerise dates (with use of partition by to numerise dates for each organization and not by all list). All this we put in cte. Then join cte with itself. Dense_rank needed here to join it with previous row and there we add one more case, that previous date must be more tnen 12 month from current.